# Someone to clarify /tags and /branches in SVN (subversion)?

Tags: svn

I created folders /tags, /branches and /trunk on SVN server. I put initial project file into /trunk. But other folders confuses me.

What should I put in /tags? I see most people do not ever use this folder. Is this like a temp folder or so?

As I understood, the purpose of branches is to host a different versions. So I will have /branches/myapp_v1.0.0, /branches/myapp_v1.0.1, etc. Right?

If this is true, how do I "tell" subversion tool (tortoise on windows, svn on linux) to upload project files into such and such folder?

Comment: It's sort of convention. Here you can find a good answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142/what-do-branch-tag-and-trunk-mean-in-subversion-repositories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **have to read** SVN Book, at least ["Fundamental Concepts"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html) and ["Basic Usage"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html)

In short: "Recommended Repository Layout" chapter tells us

> ...flexibility also means that it's easy to find yourself “lost without a roadmap” as you attempt to navigate different Subversion repositories which may carry completely different and unpredictable arrangements of the data within them.
>
> To counteract this confusion, we recommend that you follow a repository layout convention (established long ago, in the nascency of the Subversion project itself) in which a handful of strategically named Subversion repository directories convey valuable meaning about the data they hold. **Most projects have a recognizable “main line”, or trunk, of development; some branches, which are divergent copies of development lines; and some tags, which are named, stable snapshots of a particular line of development.**

Comment: This may also help to clarify things: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.planning.html